# WFLYEJB0406: No EJB found with interface of type 'ejb_accountcrud.IAccountCrud' for binding controller.LoginBean/accountServ

Tags: jpa, jdbc, auto-generate

I can't figure out what the problem is. I had already tried  org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect, enabling hybernate and other things i found over internet, but nothing seems to point what is the problem.

I have already created some other projects, but it's the first time I encounter this thing.

Table A

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

@Entity
@Table (name ="abbigliamento",uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames= {"prezzo"}))
public class Abbigliamento implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6587541972395128627L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column (name="id")
    private int id;
    @Column (name="nome")
    private String nome;
    @Column (name="taglia")
    private String taglia;
    @Column (name="colore")
    private String colore;
    @Column (name="descrizione")
    private String descrizione;
    @Column (name="quantita")
    private int quantita;
    @Column (name="disponibilita")
    private boolean disponibilita;
    @Column(name="prezzo",unique=true, nullable=false)
    private double prezzo;
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="Id_reparto")
    private Reparti reparti;
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="bolla_acquisto")
    private BollaacquistoAbbigliamento bollaAcquisto;
    //getter/setter
```

Table B

```
@Entity
@Table (name  ="bollaacquistoabbigliamento", uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames= {"codice_acquisto"}) )
public class BollaacquistoAbbigliamento implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3084091051025520907L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(name="nome_fornitore/venditore")
    private String nomeFV;
    @Column(name="codice_acquisto", unique=true,nullable=false)
    private long codiceAcquisto;
    @Column(name="data_acquisto")
    private String dataAcquisto;
    @Column(name="stock_acquistato")
    private String stock;
    @Column(name="prezzo_totale")
    private double prTotale;
    @Column(name="prezzo_unitario")
    private double prUnitario;
    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    private Abbigliamento abbigliamento;
```

Console error

> [org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76) GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table bollaacquistoabbigliamento (codice_acquisto bigint not null, data_acquisto varchar(255), nome_fornitore/venditore varchar(255), prezzo_totale double, prezzo_unitario double, stock_acquistato varchar(255), abbigliamento_id integer not null, primary key (abbigliamento_id))" via JDBC Statement: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table bollaacquistoabbigliamento (codice_acquisto bigint not null, data_acquisto varchar(255), nome_fornitore/venditore varchar(255), prezzo_totale double, prezzo_unitario double, stock_acquistato varchar(255), abbigliamento_id integer not null, primary key (abbigliamento_id))" via JDBC Statement
> at org.hibernate@5.3.10.Final//org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
> at org.hibernate@5.3.10.Final//org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559)
> at org.hibernate@5.3.10.Final//org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504)
> at org.hibernate@5.3.10.Final//org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:277)
> at org.hibernate@5.3.10.Final//org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:71)
> at org.hibernate@5.3.10.Final//org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207)
> at org.hibernate@5.3.10.Final//org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114)
> at org.hibernate@5.3.10.Final//org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183)
> at org.hibernate@5.3.10.Final//org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
> at org.hibernate@5.3.10.Final//org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:310)
> at org.hibernate@5.3.10.Final//org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467)
> at org.hibernate@5.3.10.Final//org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:939)
> at org.hibernate.jipijapa-hibernate5-3@17.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
> at org.jboss.as.jpa@17.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:170)
> at org.jboss.as.jpa@17.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:128)
> at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.9.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:649)
> at org.jboss.as.jpa@17.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:212)
> at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
> at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
> at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
> at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
> at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unknown data type: "/"; SQL statement:
> create table bollaacquistoabbigliamento (codice_acquisto bigint not null, data_acquisto varchar(255), nome_fornitore/venditore varchar(255), prezzo_totale double, prezzo_unitario double, stock_acquistato varchar(255), abbigliamento_id integer not null, primary key (abbigliamento_id)) [50004-193]
> at com.h2database.h2@1.4.193//org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
> at com.h2database.h2@1.4.193//org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
> at com.h2database.h2@1.4.193//org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
> at com.h2database.h2@1.4.193//org.h2.command.Parser.parseColumnWithType(Parser.java:4080)
> at com.h2database.h2@1.4.193//org.h2.command.Parser.parseColumnForTable(Parser.java:3938)
> at com.h2database.h2@1.4.193//org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreateTable(Parser.java:5977)
> at com.h2database.h2@1.4.193//org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreate(Parser.java:4238)
> at com.h2database.h2@1.4.193//org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:362)
> at com.h2database.h2@1.4.193//org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:317)
> at com.h2database.h2@1.4.193//org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:289)
> at com.h2database.h2@1.4.193//org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:254)
> at com.h2database.h2@1.4.193//org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:561)
> at com.h2database.h2@1.4.193//org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:502)
> at com.h2database.h2@1.4.193//org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1203)
> at com.h2database.h2@1.4.193//org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:170)
> at com.h2database.h2@1.4.193//org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:158)
> at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.16.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedStatement.execute(WrappedStatement.java:198)
> at org.hibernate@5.3.10.Final//org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
> ... 22 more

Same error also occurs for other 2 tables.

Thanks a lot and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it helps to read error messages:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unknown data type: "/"; SQL statement: create table bollaacquistoabbigliamento (codice_acquisto bigint not null, data_acquisto varchar(255), nome_fornitore/venditore varchar(255), prezzo_totale double, prezzo_unitario double, stock_acquistato varchar(255), abbigliamento_id integer not null, primary key (abbigliamento_id))
```

So maybe you shouldn't name a column `nome_fornitore/venditore` because the forward slash causes the error.